# Sending variable name vector to glm inside R function

Tags: r

I want to write a function which will take three arguments:

`df` a `data.frame`

`Y` a character with the name of one of the `df` columns

`X` a character vector of names of the `df` columns.

The function should output the `glm` of `Y` on `X`.

For example `fun(df, Y = "Price", X = c("sqft", "rooms"))` should output the same object as

`glm(Price ~ sqft + rooms, data = df)`.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: See `?as.formula`.

Comment: Also `reformulate` can be super helpful. Here, I think you'd have `reformulate(X, Y)` or `reformulate(c("sqft", "rooms"), "Price")`.

Comment: @Imo Thanks, Reformulate works perfectly!